# Does smartpy propagate exceptions?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, error

I'm doing something like this, but the invalid scenario assertion fails.

Is there a way to propagate the exception from the other contract? Or do I just have to test that contract separately?

```
class TezosHomepageAdNft(FA2):
@sp.entry_point
    def mint(self, params):
      sp.failwith("fail")

class TezosHomepage(sp.Contract):
@sp.entry_point
    def buy(self, params):
        sp.transfer(token_params, sp.tez(0), land_nft_contract)  # calling mint here

def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    t_home = TezosHomepage()
    
    scenario += t_home
    scenario += t_home.buy().run(sender = mark, amount = sp.mutez(1), valid=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartPy test interpreter already handles internal operations failures really well.

Here is an example: https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmV3nwdkwHGXdJbWwV8LDgm3TPbC49Es7Wm6GufMeh8Pz2&k=184987b7b8089b73396a

Please, don't provide incomplete examples. I always find myself wasting tremendous amounts of time just to put those examples to work.

Comment: sorry about that. I'll include a link to smartpy ide example next time. 

this time it was a user error... had a hardcoded contract address when I should've been using the one instantiated in the scenario